# How to get the AT Terminal command log (Linux) from Mobile Partner Modem Software?

Tags: linux, shell, logging, reverse-engineering, modem

I am trying to figure the AT command set issued by the Hauwei's Mobile Partner Software for making voice and video call. Mobile Partner is the bundled software for almost all Hauwei 3G Modems and comes with ability to make and receive voice calls. I need to know the AT commands it issues for my E1732 modem for voice, VIDEO calls and other things.I need the log. I have the Mobile Partner for Linux(Ubuntu) and Windows.It is working in both platforms. So any help in either of the platforms is appreciated.

My aim is to make a Linux based IVR system so I need them.
Thanks for your help

Comment: So, you are using the modem for voice calls, not data connections?

Comment: yes its for voice and video calls

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at usbsnoop as all these devices are actually emulating serial communication across usb.

Also, have a look at USB modeswitch

- [homepage](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/)
- [debian repo](http://packages.debian.org/sid/usb-modeswitch)

Modeswitch packs a lot of vendor specific 'magic' knowledge, that has been obtained by reverse engineering. Of course it was geered towards switching the USB device to 'modem' mode in the first place, but I suspect their developer list will have ample resources on tracing usb traffic.

Also, **[UMTSMon](http://umtsmon.sourceforge.net/)** is Open Source code that allowed me to use several brands of 'unsupported' (*undocumented*) USB UMTS dongles in the past. UMTSMon will send specific sequences of AT commands if you want. I assume again, that the developer list will help you gather more information.

Disclaimer: I only used the mentioned packages, and have not been involved in their development

Comment: Thanks .will look into it and let u know.

Comment: I already took care of switching problem by giving AT^U2DIAG=0 - only Modem - using Hyper terminal.Now it is just a modem.after monitoring it sends the following command for voice call - AT#CLS=8 AT+VSM=1 AT+CMUT=0 AT+CLVL=4 ATD9xxxxxxxx; AT#VTX  and then a lot of data i cant understand. guessing that to be the audio data. Now just need to figure out the codec. Any ideas on what codec it might be using?